# How to plot density of two datasets on same scale in one figure?

Tags: r, plot

How to plot the density of a single column dataset as dots?  For example

```
x <- c(1:40)
```

On the same plot using the same scale of the x-axis and y-axis, how to add another data set as line format which represent the density of another data that represents the equation of

```
y = exp(-x)
```

to the plot?

The equation is corrected to be `y = exp(-x)`.

So, by doing `plot(density(x))` or `plot(density(y))`, I got two separated figures.  How to add them in the same axis and using dots for x, smoothed line for y?

Comment: So far your question is incoherent. The expression 'y-exp-x' cannot be interpreted. Use valid R syntax.

Comment: Your code does not produce a plot, did you leave something out?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a line to a plot with the `lines()` function. Your code, modified to do what you asked for, is the following:

```
x <- 1:40
y <- exp(-x)

plot(density(x), type = "p")
lines(density(y))
```

Note that we specified the plot to give us points with the `type` parameter and then added the density curve for y with `lines`. The help pages for `?plot`, `?par`, `?lines` would be some insightful reading. Also, check out the [R Graph Gallery](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/) to view some more sophisticated graphs that generally have the source code attached to them.